# Excel Interop - prompt to save excel not appearing - c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop

I am using Excel Interop to export a dataset to excel file. The below code exports and opens the excel file directly. I need a prompt to ask the user to save, open and cancel. Please help..

```
 public static void CreateWorkbook(DataSet ds, String path)
{
    int rowindex = 0;
    int columnindex = 0;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application wapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wsheet;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wbook;

    wapp.Visible = false;

    wbook = wapp.Workbooks.Add(true);
    wsheet = (Worksheet)wbook.ActiveSheet;

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            wsheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = ds.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName;

        }

        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            rowindex++;
            columnindex = 0;
            foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
            {
                columnindex++;
                wsheet.Cells[rowindex + 1, columnindex] = row[col.ColumnName];
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String err = ex.Message;
    }
    wapp.UserControl = true;
    wapp.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Searching around, you should be able to find plenty of references for how to open dialogs or directly `Save Open Close` a `Workbook`.  It's also not clear when you want to perform those actions.  Please add more detail to your question.

Comment: Hi Byron. Thanks for your reply. The execution of the above code, simply opens the excel file directly. Instead i want to prompt excel dialog to save, open and cancel. I couldn't find any reference for this particular action. Please advise.

Comment: Save what?  Can you link to a screenshot of the dialog you are trying to show?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an old-ish question at this point, but if you are still looking for help:

Simply said, you need a SaveFileDialog or an OpenFileDialog, which I'd imagine you can see which each does.

It's simple enough to make as well:

```
SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
```

See this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) for reference.

OpenFileDialogs work the same way, but keep in mind that these dialogs **don't actually do anything on their own.** All that these dialogs do is define file names and locations when the user hits OK (and they are stored as properties).

There's two ways to work with these: Using the Event FileOk (Raised when OK is clicked) or using the method showDialog(). It's a lot easier to work with when you use the method.

As an example, if you are opening a file:

```
If saveDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK Then
   /// Do stuff, like save the Excel sheet to the path in the dialog.
End If
```

Note what this does in itself, though: it **only sets a file name as typed out in the dialog. It does not save anything. You'll still need to call the save/open methods with Excel interop methods.**

Keep in mind you can preset certain things like initial directory or file types **above** that If statement using the respective properties listed in that article.

In your case, I see 'path' as an argument to the method. What you could do is before this method call (use an OpenFileDialog, of course), add in the above If/Then block to get the 'open' path, and pass in the dialog.fileName property as the path to your method.

Putting that all together, for opening:

```
OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

If openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK Then
       CreateWorkbook(ds:= dataset, openDialog.fileName)
End If
```

Again, **remember this doesn't actually open it**. Somewhere in your method, after you define the workbook, you can open it with wbook.Open(path).

And for closing, I'd avoid giving the user control or making the app visible outside of debugging. That's asking for issues left and right.

Instead, insert this in that location in your method:

```
SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

If saveDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK Then
     wbook.Close(True, saveDialog.fileName, )
Else
     wbook.Close(False, , )
End If

wapp.Quit()
```

Once you do that, manually open the Excel for editing if its still necessary. Depending on what you need, you might need to tinker around with that idea, but I think this is generally what you need.

**EDIT: For understanding my code with the wbook.Close, see the Workbook.Close Method in the MSDN:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.close.aspx